# ZipArchive sending corrupt files

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I am using the ZipArchive class to create a ZIP file and stream it to the client but all archives are not generated correctly.

Any suggestions?

```
<?php
if(file_exists('../../../thure/uploads/nestingen/58861.pdf'))
{
    $files = array('../../../thure/uploads/nestingen/58861.pdf');
    $zipname = 'file.zip';
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
      $zip->addFile($file);
    }
    $zip->close();

    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
    readfile($zipname);

    exit;
}
else
{
    echo 'file not found';
}
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Function (writed by David)

```
/* creates a compressed zip file */
function create_zip($files = array(),$destination = '',$overwrite = false) {
    //if the zip file already exists and overwrite is false, return false
    if(file_exists($destination) && !$overwrite) { return false; }
    //vars
    $valid_files = array();
    //if files were passed in...
    if(is_array($files)) {
        //cycle through each file
        foreach($files as $file) {
            //make sure the file exists
            if(file_exists($file)) {
                $valid_files[] = $file;
            }
        }
    }
    //if we have good files...
    if(count($valid_files)) {
        //create the archive
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        if($zip->open($destination,$overwrite ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
            return false;
        }
        //add the files
        foreach($valid_files as $file) {
            $zip->addFile($file,$file);
        }
        //debug
        //echo 'The zip archive contains ',$zip->numFiles,' files with a status of ',$zip->status;

        //close the zip -- done!
        $zip->close();

        //check to make sure the file exists
        return file_exists($destination);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Sample Usage

```
$files_to_zip = array(
    'file1',
    'file2',
    'file3'
);
//if true, good; if false, zip creation failed
$result = create_zip($files_to_zip,'my-archive.zip');
```

Comment: No error in the output on screen, but in the downloaded zip file, see TS.